# Android.view.ContextMenu displays too small to use

Tags: android, android-studio, contextmenu

I'm trying to show a simple context menu (long-touch, popup text-only menu appears with options for the item you long-touched). This used to work about 5-6 years ago when I first wrote this app for my company, but since then we haven't even looked at it and now I need to add a new feature and found out this isn't working any more.

The problem is the height of the menu is limited by the vertical distance between the parent object and the screen top. In other words, the bottom of the context menu is aligned vertically with the GUI object that creates it and will only grow up, not down. If the object that creates the menu is near the bottom of the screen this works fine because there is plenty of room above it, but if it's at the top of the screen you end up with a "menu" that is like 10 pixels tall and you can't read any of the contents.

This behavior was observed on a Google Pixel XL running Android 10.0. My project is targeting Android 9.0.

Comment: can you add a screenshot, it will be easier to understand your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default context menu positioned changed in latest android versions so now it popup above tapped point. It affects older themes what do not aware of a change.

Adding this into your style customization should help.

```
 <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it. As you might imagine by now I've resolved this in a different way but this knowledge will still come in handy in the future.